# Why car and motorcycle are not packaged with box?

Tags: motorcycle, car

Why car and motorcycle are not packaged with box?

Please answer me with proper reason. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no maintenance or repair question.

Comment: Personally, I would rather have [my car _be_ the box](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3261232/Just-don-t-drive-home-rain-Lexus-creates-working-size-vehicle-CARDBOARD-worker-s-origami-skills.html), not be packaged _in_ the box.

Answer (score 5):

Motorcycles are often shipped in crates by manufacturers

[image: Honda motorcycle crate]

Answer (score 2):

1) cost, waste material - however, some cars are shipped with protective coatings.
2) practicality : being able to drive the cars is easier than moving them by forklift for example.
3) the extra volume caused by the packaging - think of the volume necessary in a container ship for example.

This is not really Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair question - are you getting us to do your homework?

Answer (score 2):

They are but only by exception for either shipping or promotional reasons.

[image: Porsche Cayman]

This Porsche was placed in a cardboard box, similar to the box used for model cars, purely for promotional reasons.

[image: Lambo is shipping crate]

This Lamborghini shows how low volume production cars are packaged to be shipped around the world.  Typically any low volume or specialist classic car crossing the atlantic will be sent this way.

Comment: By Strasbourg Peugeot have a "car park" so full, numbered in thousands, of new cars - none packaged ! just covered in a protective wax waiting for orders...

Comment: Indeed, it is by exception that they are ever packaged within boxes.

Comment: Agreed yes and also some manufacturers do not like their cars "visible" on a trailer especially when broken down (but XXX never breakdown!!)

Comment: Is it worth more if it is still in the box? Had to award you a point here.